# How do I invert a matrix in tensorflow-js?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Simple question. Is there an operation for it, also, how do you create an identity matrix? I've checked the documentation but can't find a single operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now tensorflowJs does not have any direct operator that can return the inverse of a matrix M.
You can consider using the module [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/inv.html)

Having said that, it is possible to invert a matrix using tensorflowJs operators.

The following calculates the inverse of a matrix using the **adjoint method** with tensorflowJs operators.

```js
// calculate the determinant of a matrix m
function det(m) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        const [r, _] = m.shape
        if (r === 2) {
            const t = m.as1D()
            const a = t.slice([0], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            const b = t.slice([1], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            const c = t.slice([2], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            const d = t.slice([3], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            result = a * d - b * c
            return result

        } else {
            let s = 0;
            rows = [...Array(r).keys()]
            for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                sub_m = m.gather(tf.tensor1d(rows.filter(e => e !== i), 'int32'))
                sli = sub_m.slice([0, 1], [r - 1, r - 1])
                s += Math.pow(-1, i) * det(sli)
            }
            return s
        }
    })
}

// the inverse of the matrix : matrix adjoint method
function invertMatrix(m) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        const d = det(m)
        if (d === 0) {
            return
        }
        [r, _] = m.shape
        rows = [...Array(r).keys()]
        dets = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                const sub_m = m.gather(tf.tensor1d(rows.filter(e => e !== i), 'int32'))
                let sli
                if (j === 0) {
                    sli = sub_m.slice([0, 1], [r - 1, r - 1])
                } else if (j === r - 1) {
                    sli = sub_m.slice([0, 0], [r - 1, r - 1])
                } else {
                    const [a, b, c] = tf.split(sub_m, [j, 1, r - (j + 1)], 1)
                    sli = tf.concat([a, c], 1)
                }
                dets.push(Math.pow(-1, (i + j)) * det(sli))
            }
        }
        com = tf.tensor2d(dets, [r, r])
        tr_com = com.transpose()
        inv_m = tr_com.div(tf.scalar(d))
        return inv_m
    })
}

const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4], [3, 3])
console.log("matrix a")
a.print()
const i = invertMatrix(a)
console.log("inverse i")
i.print()
const prod = i.dot(a)
console.log("a * i")
prod.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the **Jordan-Gauss** method, one can calculate the inverse of the matrix this way:

```js
// calculate the determinant of a matrix m
function det(m) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        const [r, _] = m.shape
        if (r === 2) {
            const t = m.as1D()
            const a = t.slice([0], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            const b = t.slice([1], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            const c = t.slice([2], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            const d = t.slice([3], [1]).dataSync()[0]
            result = a * d - b * c
            return result

        } else {
            let s = 0;
            rows = [...Array(r).keys()]
            for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                sub_m = m.gather(tf.tensor1d(rows.filter(e => e !== i), 'int32'))
                sli = sub_m.slice([0, 1], [r - 1, r - 1])
                s += Math.pow(-1, i) * det(sli)
            }
            return s
        }
    })
}

// the inverse of the matrix : jordan-gauss method
function invertM(m) {
    return tf.tidy(() => {
        if (det(m) === 0) {
            return
        }
        const [r, _] = m.shape
        let inv = m.concat(tf.eye(r), 1)
        rows = [...Array(r).keys()]
        for (let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            inv = tf.tidy(() => {
                for (let j = i + 1; j < r; j++) {
                    const elt = inv.slice([j, i], [1, 1]).as1D().asScalar()
                    const pivot = inv.slice([i, i], [1, 1]).as1D().asScalar()
                    let newrow
                    if (elt.dataSync()[0] !== 0) {
                        newrow = inv.gather(tf.tensor1d([i], 'int32')).sub(inv.gather(tf.tensor1d([j], 'int32')).div(elt).mul(pivot)).as1D()
                        const sli = inv.gather(rows.filter(e => e !== j))
                        const arr = []
                        if (j === 0) {
                            arr.push(newrow)
                        }
                        sli.unstack().forEach((t, ind) => {
                            if (ind !== j) {
                                arr.push(t)
                            } else {
                                arr.push(newrow)
                                arr.push(t)
                            }
                        })
                        if (j === r - 1) {
                            arr.push(newrow)
                        }
                        inv = tf.stack(arr)
                    }
                }
                return inv
            })
        }
        const trian = tf.unstack(inv)
        len = trian.length
        trian[len - 1] = trian[len - 1].div(trian[len - 1].slice(trian[len - 1].shape[0] - 1, 1).asScalar())
        for (let i = r - 2; i > -1; i--) {
            for (j = r - 1; j > i; j--) {
                trian[i] = trian[i].sub(trian[j].mul(trian[i].slice(j, 1).asScalar()))
            }
            trian[i] = trian[i].div(trian[i].slice(i, 1).asScalar())
        }
        return tf.split(tf.stack(trian), 2, 1)[1]
    })
}

const a = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4], [3, 3])
console.log("matrix a")
a.print()
const i = invertM(a)
console.log("inverse i")
i.print()
const prod = i.dot(a)
console.log("a * i")
prod.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for verifying that for me. I'm trying to solve an unconstrained nonlinear minimization problem and the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm requires the inverse operation. I've implemented it in Math.js but it is too slow so I was hoping an ml library would have some quick matrix manipulation capabilities. So far numeric has been the swiftest. Do you think it's feasible to use the built-in minimization functions of tf to solve these sorts of problems?

Comment: It is feasible to built your own implementation of a function that inverts a matrix using tfjs operators. Consider the edit to my answer

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, it's very helpful. The code seems to be very slow when applied to moderately sized matrices. Do you know why that is? The inverse operation is implemented in regular TensorFlow and it doesn't suffer from that issue. I may look into how that is done.

Comment: The adjoint method is a very poor algorithm in practice because of it's complexity due to the calculation of each determinant. The jordan-Gauss method is preferred for big matrixes

Comment: These functions don't work correctly. det function works.

Comment: Do you mean the `invertM` does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

For the identity matrix you can use [`tf.eye()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#eye) and I am not sure what you mean by inverting a matrix but it could either be [`tf.reciprocal()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#reciprocal) which performs `1/x` element-wise or you want to transpose it, which would be done using [`tf.transpose()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#transpose).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mean a matrix where given matrix A the inverse is defined as the matrix B where AB = I, and I is the identity matrix.